# How to create a json array from certain csv columns with pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

I have a csv file with around a thousand of rows looks like:

```
id,name,email,date_of_birth,arrive_time
4657,name1,email1,01/10/1987,15:50
7594,name2,email2,02/10/1987,10:05
```

I need to convert it in json array view of:

```
[
      {
        "name": "name1",
        "date_of_birth": "01/10/1987"
      },
      {
        "name": "name2",
        "date_of_birth": "02/10/1987"
      }
]
```

Code I've used:

```
import csv
import json

file = 'myCsvFile.csv'
json_file = 'myLsonFile.json'

def read_CSV(file, json_file):
    csv_rows = []
    with open(file) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        field = reader.fieldnames
        for row in reader:
            csv_rows.extend([{field[i]:row[field[i]] for i in range(len(field))}])

def convert_write_json(data, json_file):
    with open(json_file, "w") as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(data, sort_keys=False, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))
        f.write(json.dumps(data))


read_CSV(file,json_file)
```

The output of this code is

```
{
    "name": "id;name;email;date_of_birth;arrange_time",
    "date_of_birth": null
}
{
    "name": "4657;name1;email1;01/10/1987;15:50",
    "date_of_birth": null
}
```

But I can't catch how to select certain columns from csv and create an array.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv("myCsvFile.csv").to_json("myJsonFile.json")
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer found and it turns to be more simple than I expected

```
import csv
import json

    my_list = []
    with open(' myCsvFilr.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            name = row["name"]
            date_of_birth = row["date_of_birth"]
            my_dict = {"name":name, "date_of_birth":date_of_birth}   
            my_list.append(my_dict)

    with open('myJsonFile.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(my_list, outfile, indent= 4)
```